# Как связать скрипт дающий данные и скрипт их обрабатывающий

Tags: python

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Есть скрипт, подающий данные на обработку.Данные - словарь с 5-ю полями типа String.
Есть другой, их обрабатывающий.

Проблема в том что второй скрипт обрабатывает данные приличное количество времени, а первый может подкидывать работу чаще.Требуется что-то в духе буфера - первый в него даёт работу, второй пишет результат.

Я сначала пытался использовать threading но дело до конца довести не смог.
Каким на ваш взгляд будет оптимальное решение?

Comment: В том же threading есть Queue, который именно этим и занимается